# Determine whether u has an adjoint w.r.t. to the given bilinear form

Tags: matrices

Let $E$ be a vector space and $u \in L(E)$. For the following case, determine whether $u$ has an adjoint with respect to the given bilinear form $\phi (x,y)$.

$E = \{ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: f $ is a polynomial $\}$,

$\phi(f,g) = \int_0^1 f(t)g(t) dt$

$u(f) = \int_0^1 \frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{t}}dt$

Let $A$ be the matrix representation of $u$

Let $B$ be the matrix representation of $\phi$

$A$ is self-adjoint w.r.t. $\phi$ iff $\langle Av, w \rangle  = v^TA^TBw = v^TBAw =\langle v, Aw \rangle $

So I need to check if: $A^TB = BA$.

But how can I represent $\phi$ and $u$ as matrices? I don't see how since f,g are polynomials with no maximal degree

Comment: LaTex note: for expressions like $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ one usually uses `\to` instead of `\rightarrow`. They don’t always render the same way, and `\to` carries the correct semantics.

Comment: As you’ve noted, you can’t really represent $\phi$ and $u$ as matrices. Do you know any definition of the adjoint of an operator that don’t involve its matrix representation? Hint: it looks very much like the one you’ve got already.

Comment: In the title of your question and its first part, you’re asking whether or not $u$ even has an adjoint, but in the latter part you’ve moved beyond that and appear to be asking whether or not $u$ is self-adjoint. Which is your actual question here?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The question is whether $u$ has an adjoint or not. I assumed that adjoint and self-adjoint is the same. This is wrong, right? Self-adjoint would be if I take twice the same vector?

Comment: “Self-adjoint” means that the function is its own adjoint. Obviously, if you can show that $u$ is self-adjoint, then it has an adjoint.

Comment: A representation that doesn‘t involve matrices, but much like this? Did I understand the hint correctly?

Comment: Hard to tell. Do you have any definition of the adjoint of an operator that uses the operator itself instead of a matrix representation of it?

Comment: I‘m not sure about this, but this Theorem is in our script in the chapter about „Adjoint of an endomorphism“:

Let $u \in L(E)$. There exists a element of $L(E)$ that we denote by $u‘$ s.t. For any $(x,y) \in E^2$

$(u(x),y) = (x,u‘(y))$ In addition for any $x,y \in E$

$(x,u(y))=(u‘(x),y)$

Comment: There you go. So, you have a definition of the inner product to use and the function $u$. Might as well see if $u$ is self-adjoint, so write out the corresponding expressions and see if they’re equal.

Comment: Unfortunately this theorem isn‘t clear for me. Is there a name for this so I can google it and try to understand it better?

Comment: So this theorem says if I take $u$ which is a linear application. There exists another linear application denoted $u‘$ s.t. (u(x),y) = (x,u‘(y)). Do these (. , .) stand for the inner product?

Comment: That’s correct.

Comment: So, I tried to apply the theorem:

I will have to check if $(u(x),y)=(x,u'(y))$. In my task:

$u(f) = \int_0^1 \frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{t}} dt$,

(. , .) $= \phi (f,g) = \int_0^1 f(t)g(t) dt$ If I apply this:

$(u(f),g)= \int_0^1 (\int_0^1 \frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{t}}dt)g(t)dt$ and

$(f, u'(g)) = \int_0^1 f(t) u'(g) dt$

I will have to check if :

$(\int_0^1 \frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{t}}dt) g(t)$ is equal to $f(t) u'(g)$

But can $u'$ be any linear application? or what are the further steps?

Comment: Actually, this theorem says that for any linear application $u \in L(E)$ there exists an adjoint. I know that $u$ is linear. So shouldn't it be that according to this Theorem there exists an adjoint?

Comment: This works only for finite-dimensional vector spaces - but then I have no clue how to compute the adjoint.